# WCF and error stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, wcf-data-services

I have a stored procedure which returns the status of databasemail in SQL Server, which return string "stopped" or "started". I must use it in C#, Silverlight and WCF Data Service.

Here's my code:

```
contex.BeginExecute<String>(new Uri(uri2), OnQueryComplete3, null);
...
private void OnQueryComplete3(IAsyncResult result)
{
   grLog.ItemsSource = contex.EndExecute<String>(result).ToList<String>();
}
```

And I have error:

> Error processing response stream. The XML element contains mixed
>   content.

The service operation:

```
[WebGet]
public IQueryable<String> Status_Serwer()
{
return CurrentDataSource
.status_serwer()
.AsQueryable();
}
```

I find ".NET 4.0 still doesn't support materialization of responses from service operations returning primitive or complex types (or collections  of those)." in this duscussion http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/incoking-webget-throws-exception-56000.aspx. Is it true?

Comment: Can you find out what the result of `contex.EndExecute<String>(result)` is, and post it here?

Comment: Even better - could you please grab the response using tools like Fiddler (or any other HTTP tracer) and post it here? Also, how is the service operation defined in the service (what is the return type)?

Answer (score 0):

IQueryable is normaly used for a list that hasn't been executed yet, and requires interactive iteration. Because you are pulling your data together on the server it may be better to pull the entire list of status records and then send them to your client. Try using a List instead of IQueryable in your response. Note that List is serializable.

Assuming that "CurrentDataSource.status_serwer()" returns an enumerable list of strings, this code might do the trick:

```
[WebGet]
public List<String> Status_Serwer()
{
    return CurrentDataSource
          .status_serwer()
          .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Are you attempting to return a list of responses, or only a single response ("stopped" or "started")? If only a single response, then you can simply return a string instead of attempting to return a list of objects.

Comment: Just ran across this post, which might be helpful: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/2341c11e-92b3-4da4-aba5-858054f46c80/. If you are using a primitive "WebGet" operation through REST, it appears that you are limited to strings and can't use collections.